# Return string Input with parse.string

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

I'm having an issue with a java program trying to get a string input from a joptionpane menu with a prompt box. With returning a string input. 
I don't know if im going about it all wrong by trying to use

```
String.parseString(input)
```

Im very much a beginner with this so any help would have to be as simple as possible or a correction outright.

```
   private static String getStringInput (String prompt) {
         String input = EZJ.getUserInput(prompt);
         return String.parseString(input);
   }


UseCalls.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
         return String.parseString(input);
                      ^
 symbol:   method parseString(String)
 location: class String
 1 error
```

Here is a sample of the menu Im trying to use it with

```
    do {

        userInput = mainMenu();

        if (userInput.equals("1")) {
            String name = getStringInput("Name?");
            String address = getStringInput("Address?");
            call[numCalls++] = new Call();
        }
        } while (!userInput.equals("0"));


}
```

Here is the EZJ mini method

```
public class EZJ {

public static String getUserInput (String prompt) {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
}
public static void dialog(String inputValue) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, inputValue );
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to parse the string, it's defined as a string already.

Just do:

```
    private static String getStringInput (String prompt) {
     String input = EZJ.getUserInput(prompt);
     return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you see in an error `UseCalls.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
         return String.parseString(input);` there is no method `parseString` in `String` class. There is no need to parse it as long as `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);` already returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really bent upon converting Integer to String value, I suggest use String.valueOf(YourIntegerVariable). More details can be found at: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm